# how to deal with interrupts that calls a subroutine from a subroutine?

Tags: interrupt, interrupt-handling

say there is a call to a subroutine `Multiply`. while the main function has called the subroutine and we are in the middle of the sub routine's execution an external interrupt occurs which also calls the same subroutine `multiply`. what will happen in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an interrupt occurs, the information about the running program is saved away and then the *[interrupt handler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_handler)* is started.  This handler runs on a *[stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack)* that is separate from the one that the interrupted program uses, so if the handler calls `multiply` it will have separate parameters, local variables, and return addresses from what the program had.